# Is there anyway to send an Email Alert to a Territory Assignee?

Tags: workflow, email-alert, territory-management

We have implemented Territory Management in our Org. In our scenario, we have multiple business units which divide their territories differently and we keep one Account for all the business units.

Recently, one business unit requested that they receive and email alert 30 days before a date. That business unit has a territory, lets call it territory 1, that covers it. This Account also falls under Territory A and Territory Orange for the different business units. Is there a way for me to send this email alert out to just the person assigned to territory 1? Right now the only viable solution seems to be Public Groups and somehow populate the public group with the assigned users for teach territory. Is it possible to do that with a batch job?

Comment: is your question -- can public groups be populated via a batch job?  Or are you trying to find an alternative way to send email alerts to users in one of n Territories for a given, workflow-triggered account?

Comment: Well I'm trying to find the best way to send email alerts to users in one of the Territories given. One of my ideas is to set public groups up and update them with territory users but thinking this through I would have to somehow populate the groups on the Account record so that I can reference them in an Email Alert